# Encountered with JPA ManytoMany Relationship Build time errors with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm very new to this topic so i followed a tutorial. after following steps i got some build time errors.

I have imported javax persistence like this.

```
import javax.persistence.*;
```

Then the student model class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="STUDENT")
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer studentId;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="Enrollment", joinColumns = {@JoinColumns(name="student_id")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumns(name="course_id")})
    private List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

The Course model class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="COURSE")
public class Course {
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy ="courses")
    private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
```

These are set of errors that i have got

**incompatible types: javax.persistence.JoinColumns cannot be converted to javax.persistence.JoinColumn**

**cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method name()
  location: @interface javax.persistence.JoinColumns**

**annotation @javax.persistence.JoinColumns is missing a default value for the element 'value'**

Can anyone help me to get rid of this issues?
Thanks.

Comment: It is customary to show that steps you've take to try to fix this yourself. That is so you don't waste our time and we don't waste yours. So what have you tried? What did you get from reading the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumns.html?

Comment: To state the obvious ... `@JoinColumns` has one attribute ... "value". There is no attribute "name" so don't do that. The "value" should be an array of `@JoinColumn`. `@JoinColumn` has an attribute "name" (so just change `@JoinColumns` to `@JoinColumn` - is it that hard?. You will find all of this IN ANY JPA reference document. Suggest that you read one. http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_2/jpa/mapping.html#one_many_join_uni   Oh, and this is basic Java, applying to any use of Java annotations

Comment: Dear @RandyCasburn I`m very sorry if i waste your time.i tried plenty of time to get solve this. if i see the problem as yours see why i should come to hear to ask it? .. probably you might be a genius in the field but i`m not. i learned something here.

Comment: @BillyFrost Thank you very much.

Comment: I wasn't trying to be mean. As the code of conduct requests, I was trying to be nice and to help you get to a solution more quickly. I might recommend you re-read the [Site Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) section titled: _Get answers to practical, detailed questions_, where it specifically says: **Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do.**

Comment: @RandyCasburn I`m struggling at coding. i want to be a prof at programming. as i`m a newer can you please give me some tips? i want to start and improve my self. i dont know how to start like wise some help need. any social media? i wanna have a little chat with you pls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `@JoinTable` annotation really has a *joinColumns* parameter, but the syntax you had used is not correct. If tables are joined by only column and inverse column you shouldn't use a `@JoinColumns` annotation. You have to change it in the following way:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="STUDENT")
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer studentId;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
      name="Enrollment", 
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="student_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="course_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and only if joining goes by more then one column you have to do something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="STUDENT")
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer studentId;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
      name="Enrollment", 
      joinColumns = @JoinColumns{
        @JoinColumn(name="student_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        @JoinColumn(name="another_id", referencedColumnName = "another_id")
      },
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="course_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Hope it will help